# How to fix getting a reference error of data that I passed into the ejs file when I submit the post route?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

I'm creating a web app where I send two pieces of data to a ejs file and it works when I load the page, as in the data shows up how I want it to on the page, but when I submit the post route I get a reference error and it says the data that I passed in is not defined.

My routing file in javaScript:

```
router.get("/journal/new", isLoggedIn, function(req, res){
    Goal.find({}, function(err, meansGoals){
        if(err){
           res.render("dailyJournal"); 
        } else {
            Goals.find({}, function(err, goals){
                if(err){
                    res.render("dailyJournal");
                } else {
                    res.render("dailyJournalNew", {meansGoals: meansGoals, goals: goals});
                }
            });
        }
    });
});

//post journal
router.post("/journal", isLoggedIn, function(req, res){
    Journal.create(req.body.journal, function(err, journal){
        if(err){
            res.render("dailyJournalNew");
        } else {
            journal.author.id = req.user._id;
            journal.author.username = req.user.username;
            journal.save();
            res.redirect("/journal");
        }
    });
});
```

The page loads exactly how I want with the data from meansGoals and goals, but when I submit the "journal" it says meansGoals is not defined.

```
ReferenceError: /home/ec2-user/environment/views/dailyJournalNew.ejs:52
    50|                 <input id="editbutton" class="btn btn-outline-danger" type="submit" value="Save my Journal!">
    51|                 <% var count = 0 %>
 >> 52|                 <% for(i = 0; i < meansGoals.length; i++){ %>
    53|                     <% if(currentUser.username === meansGoals[i].author.username){ %>
    54|                         <% if(count === 0){ %>
    55|                             <% count++ %>

meansGoals is not defined
```

If you need more context or info just ask. I've been stuck on this for awhile and I really appreciate the help! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This means the `if(err)` condition in `router.post("/journal"` is activated. You are not passing `meansGoals` there.